# OnLocationUpdatedListener in Oreo does not work

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have this code

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

                UtilsDialog.displayPromptForEnablingGPS(MainActivity.this);
            }
            SmartLocation.with(getApplicationContext()).location()
                    .oneFix()
                    .start(new OnLocationUpdatedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onLocationUpdated(Location location) {

                            double Lat = location.getLatitude();
                            double Lng = location.getLongitude();
                            LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(Lat, Lng);
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coordinate).title("you are here").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_map_pin)));

                            CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(coordinate);
                            mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);

                            mMap.clear();
                        }

                    });
```

I've checked this code in different versions, but in Android 8 version do not work and I used SmartLocation library
how can I fix this problem?

Comment: have you requested runntime permissions?

Comment: oh No I did not requested runntime permissions

Comment: that is likely the reason for it not to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by enable mock location app in developer option in device

[image]

this is mock location app

[image]